# Electric potential plane with periodic surface charge density

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage

let a plane xOy with a surface charge density $σ(x)= σ_0 + σ_1cos(\frac{2πx}{a})\:\:\:\: σ_1,σ_0$ and a being positive constants

the electric potential has the form $V(x,y) = V_0(z)+V_1(z)cos(\frac{2πx}{a})$

using Laplace's equation find $V_0(z)$ and $V_1(z)$

we have $\Delta V = \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial z^2}=-V_1(z)(\frac{2π}{a})^2cos(\frac{2πx}{a})+\frac{d²V_0(z)}{\mathrm{dz²}}+\frac{d²V_1(z)}{\mathrm{dz²}}cos(\frac{2πx}{a})=0$ and I can't go any further.

Comment: Use Gauss' Law  to find $E_z$ at each point, then use the general solution to Laplace's equation  in cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this problem. For example, one could use the principle of superposition, to calculate separately potentials created by $\sigma_0$ and the cosine term - in other words, to separate the equations for $V_0$ and $V_1$.